# NSInvalidArgumentException having a single dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to put `NSDictionary` data into a `tableView`. But I'm having problem when there is only one value.

Here, having one "upload" count returns 8 (but it should return 1) and if there is more than one "upload" count returns the number of "upload"'s as it should be in the first case.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = aDicLog;
NSMutableArray *tableData = jsonDictionary[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"];

int count = [tableData count];
NSLog(@"COUNT: %i", count);
```

**Table**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}
```

**Cell**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{      
   //App Crashes in this line 
   NSDictionary *ldUpload = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   ...
   return cell;
}
```

Exception, Having one "upload":

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

**The dictionary looks like this:**

Here is when the app crashes: (With just one "upload")

```
Printing description of tableData:
{
    FileName =     {
        text = "IMG_0510.MOV";
    };
    status =     {
        text = 2;
    };
    Event =     {
        text = Q;
    };
    Date =     {
        text = "9/9/2016 11:01:58 AM";
    };
    Publicacion =     {
        text = "Example";
    };
    Seccion =     {
        text = Sistemas;
    };
    idMultimedia =     {
        text = 1136;
    };
    text = "";
}
```

Here is when the app works well: (With more than one "upload")

```
Printing description of tableData:
<__NSArrayM 0x7a49dc90>(
{
    FileName =     {
        text = "1-FB5A9792.MOV";
    };
    status =     {
        text = 4;
    };
    Event =     {
        text = Test;
    };
    Date =     {
        text = "9/7/2016 9:06:21 AM";
    };
    Publicacion =     {
        text = "Example";
    };
    Seccion =     {
        text = Sistemas;
    };
    idMultimedia =     {
        text = 993;
    };
    text = "";
},
{
    FileName =     {
        text = "2-FB5A9793.MOV";
    };
    status =     {
        text = 4;
    };
    Event =     {
        text = Test;
    };
    Date =     {
        text = "9/7/2016 9:06:21 AM";
    };
    Publicacion =     {
        text = "Example";
    };
    Seccion =     {
        text = Sistemas;
    };
    idMultimedia =     {
        text = 994;
    };
    text = "";
},...
```

I´m using [XMLReader](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/) to convert an XML to `Dictionary`, then pass the above data to tableData

**XML**

```
<multimedia>
  <uploads>
    <upload>
      <id>1136</id>
      <Date>9/9/2016 11:01:58 AM</Date>
      <FileName>IMG_0510.MOV</FileName>
      <status>2</status>
      <Publicacion>Example</Publicacion>
      <Seccion>Sistemas</Seccion>
      <Event>Q</Event>
    </upload>
  </uploads>
</multimedia>
```

How can I return 1 instead of 8 when only have 1 "upload" and n in case of n "upload"'s?

Comment: When it crashes, it's because `tableData` is a `NSDictionary`, not a `NSArray`, in the case when there is only one elements, whereas when there are various elements, it's an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  check the object type and if it is `Dictionary` or `NSArray` on the basis of that generate your tableData array.

```
id uploadsObj = jsonDictionary[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"];
if ([uploadsObj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSMutableArray *tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:(NSDictionary*)uploadsObj];
}
else if ([uploadsObj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSMutableArray *tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)uploadsObj];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nirav D but in line `NSMutableArray *tableData = [arrayWithArray:(NSArray*)uploadsObj];` it shows an error `Use of undeclared identifier 'arrayWithArray'`, Do i miss something?

Comment: That was just typo mistake, check the edited answer.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift Version:

Just check if the data is a Dictionary or an Array:

```
var tableData:[[String:AnyObject]]! = []

if let data = jsonDictionary[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    print("Single upload data")
    tableData.append(data)
} else {
    if let data = jsonDictionary[@"multimedia"][@"uploads"][@"upload"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        print("multiple upload data")
        tableData = data
    }
}
```

Comment: Batter you change your answer with Objective C otherwise some will down vote you because OP is working on Objective C.

Comment: oops..I'll mention it as swift version. Because you have already posted the correct solution.